# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'OSSubscriptionObserver'

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, onesignal

This code

```
#if __has_include(<React/RCTBridgeModule.h>)
    #import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
    #elif __has_include("RCTBridgeModule.h")
    #import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
    #endif


#if __has_include(<OneSignal/OneSignal.h>)
#import <OneSignal/OneSignal.h>
#else
#import "OneSignal.h"
#endif

@interface RCTOneSignal : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule, OSSubscriptionObserver>

- (id)initWithLaunchOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions appId:(NSString *)appId;
- (id)initWithLaunchOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions appId:(NSString *)appId settings:(NSDictionary*)settings;
+ (void)didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
@end
```

This problem or error :

Cannot find protocol declaration for 'OSSubscriptionObserver'
Thanks for advance. :)

Comment: have you resolved this issue? I am facing same issue now

Comment: I have the same problem with OneSignal Android SDK. After moving from version 4 to 5, it looks like they introduced breaking changes including this one that removes the OSSubscriptionObserver class from the package. The problem is that for now I can't find in their documentation what should replace it in version 5 of the SDK.